OpenCV Template Matching for Playing Cards
For my bridge training lessons I 'm trying to analyse a deal played in Bridge Base Online, by capturing the image and then try to find where are the 52 cards.
The reference image is this one (capture.jpg)

And I have also 52 images (41x68) of the cards, like the five of spades:

Now when doing pattern matching in OpenCV:
Mat1f result;
matchTemplate(org_gray, template_gray, result, TM_CCOEFF_NORMED);
double thresh = 0.8;
threshold(result, result, thresh, 1., THRESH_BINARY);

Mat1b resb;
result.convertTo(resb, CV_8U, 255);

std::vector<std::vector<Point>> contours;
findContours(resb, contours, RETR_LIST, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); ++i)
{
    Mat1b mask(result.rows, result.cols, uchar(0));
    drawContours(mask, contours, i, Scalar(255), cv::FILLED);

    Point max_point,min_point;
    double max_val;
    minMaxLoc(result, NULL, &max_val, &min_point, &max_point, mask);

    rectangle(img, Rect(max_point.x, max_point.y, ptpw->m.cols, ptpw->m.rows), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);
}
imshow("b", ptpw->m);
imshow("a",img);

The result is this one. It did detect the location of S5 but it also detected 7 more cards...

How can I enhance my algorithm?
If I raise the threshold to 0.87 it finds only one card, but the 5 of clubs instead. I can adjust the threshold to find only one card, but why the 5C instead of 5S?
Thanks.

This question is similar to: matchTemplate() missing detections and giving false positives, what can I do?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

matchTemplate doesn't test multiple scales.

@ChristophRackwitz If  I use TM_SQDIFF_NORMED I get 50 completely out of place contours. The question is actually why, with the best threshold of 0.87 , it finds first the 5 club instead of the 5 spade.

I've been hasty. I'll look into this more thoroughly.

the one "exact" instance on the left isn't exact because the template has a wide white border while the instance is narrower, having the border of an adjacent card within the area of the template's best fit. that makes the match worse.

Hmm so I must remove borders from all my templates?

or crop in code (cropped_template = template(Rect(...))). don't remove too much though. just enough.

template matching could not help you. you should extract some features of your card then looking for similar cards.

of course template matching can help. it's a simple approach but it has its uses.

As is the case with everyone who asks, the matching mode is bad. For perfect data without brightness variations, the TM_SQDIFF* modes are the best choice.
matchTemplate(org_gray, template_gray, result, TM_SQDIFF_NORMED);
double thresh = 0.1;
threshold(result, result, thresh, 1., THRESH_BINARY_INV);

You will get a difference if the instance is red/gray, so you should consider converting to grayscale by simply taking the green or blue channel of the image (red text on white background is just all bright in the red channel). You could do that by splitting the source channels or with mixChannels, or even with transform and a custom mixing matrix.
Further, your template has a wide white border. It's too wide. On the expected perfect match, it overlaps onto the image of a neighboring card (black border, black number), reducing the quality of the match.
Trim it down. That'll do better.

SQDIFF_NORMED on the original template:

With template cropped more closely:

Even here it's not perfect because of JPEG compression artefacts. I also think the card instance's rounded edge intrudes on the square template.

And then you'll need Non-Maximum Suppression (NMS). If you just threshold the scores array, you'll get adjacent "on" pixels for the same detection, or even extrema that are almost adjacent for some reason. So don't just threshold, but do a little more. This is a general recipe with steps that were needed in various situations.
Sketch in Python:
nms_threshold = 0.10 # looking for minima
nms_radius = 5
localmin = cv.erode(scores, None, iterations=nms_radius)
extrema = (scores == localmin) & (scores <= nms_threshold)
extrema = cv.morphologyEx(extrema.astype(np.uint8), cv.MORPH_CLOSE, None, iterations=nms_radius)
# and then connected components, with stats for centroid
# will also handle minima larger than 1 pixel
(nlabels, labels, stats, centroids) = cv.connectedComponentsWithStats(extrema.astype(np.uint8))


No, the window is not resized. The capture.jpg contains the cards exactly as the templates, same size. There is no stretching.
